# Google script HTML select required did not work

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

Code (I'm working with Materialize CSS framework):

```
<form class="col s12" id="formRequer">     
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select id="stdApply" name="stdApply" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha somente uma das opções</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <label>Selecione o que quer requerer</label>
      </div>      
  </form>   <!-- END: form class="col s12" id="formRequer -->  


<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" id="btn_submitRequer" form="formRequer">Enviar
  <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
```

I copied the code excluding CSS and paste it on w3school and it worked fine!

Is it possible that HTMLService evalute() process exclude the required attribute from  tag or exclude the  value="" attribute from the first option (this is vital for HTML5 select tag works with required attribute)?

Any help?

Comment: Please eplain what you mean by `exclude the required attribute from tag`.

Comment: Where is the initialisation script for the Select? https://materializecss.com/select.html#initialization

Comment: Hi  ziganotschka, thanks for your reply.
exclude the required attribute from tag = delete the required attribute form the select tag

Comment: HI Sean Doherty, thanks for your reply. The initialization is correct and it works fine and well renderized. The only issue is that when I click on submit button it sends the form don't mind if I had choosen or not an option. In other words, if I do not choose an options the form is sended not respecting the required attribute. If < select required> it means that submit button could not send - has to show an error message: field/data required - until I choose an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <form>     
   <select id="stdApply" name="stdApply">
     <option value="" selected>Escolha somente uma das opções</option>
     <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     <option value="3">Option 3</option>
   </select>
   <label>Selecione o que quer requerer</label>
   <br /><input type="button" value="Enviar" onClick="processForm(this.parentNode);" />
  </form>  
  <script>
    function processForm(obj) {
      if(obj.stdApply.value!='') {
        google.script.run.processForm(obj);
      }else{
        document.getElementById('stdApply').focus();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Google Script:

```
function processForm(obj) {
  Browser.msgBox(obj.stdApply);
}

function showMyDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah3'), 'Test');
}
```