# Form Input Field Required attribute is not working in Google app script HTML web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Updated Codeenter image description here
If i remove 
Its show reuried filed notoifcation in input filed however if i add the jquery it's allowing me to submit the data [image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=], initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="email2" type="email" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
                    <label for="email2">Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="example" name="example" type="text" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
                    <label for="example">Field</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action"  onclick="submitForm(this)">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    
<script>
function submitForm(btnClicked) {
            $("button").attr("disabled", true);
            var jsonObj = {};
            jsonObj["FirstName"] =  $("#email2").val();
            jsonObj["MiddleName"] =  $("#example").val();

            jsonObj["Submit"] = $(btnClicked).text();
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(action).saveDate(jsonObj);
        }
        


    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Form Input Field Required attribute is not working in Google app script HTML web app

Using materialize CSS in my web app -In both the input filed have added Required attribute however on click submit button not getting any notification in input filed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=], initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="email2" type="email" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
                    <label for="email2">Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="example" name="example" type="text" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
                    <label for="example">Field</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action"  onclick="submitForm(this)">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    
<script>
function submitForm(btnClicked) {
            $("button").attr("disabled", true);
            var jsonObj = {};
            jsonObj["FirstName"] =  $("#email2").val();
            jsonObj["MiddleName"] =  $("#example").val();

            jsonObj["Submit"] = $(btnClicked).text();
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(action).saveDate(jsonObj);
        }
        


    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser did you test using? When I tested it using Chrome, the notification is shown, if this is not my misunderstanding. By the way, `the input filed` in your question is `the input field`?

Comment: Yes, Using chrome but input filed is allowing me to submit  the blank fields

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I could understand about your replying and could replicate your issue.

Comment: jQuery should always be served before Materialize. Please fix this then let’s take it from there.

Comment: @SeanDoherty i have updated but still the same result please refer the updated code

Comment: Have a look at this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61601849/11599789

Comment: I Have Updated   from TURE to FALSE      $("button").attr("disabled", false); now it's working fine